# Visual Studio Code extension - mouse middle click go to definition

Tags: visual-studio-code, webstorm

I'm searching for an extension for VS Code something like this:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=norachuga.MiddleClickDefinition
It's natively supported in WebStorm, and I want to switch to VSC and it's really annoying.
I didn't find any results on google.
Is any good tutorial or code snipped on how to create one?

Comment: trying to get this merged in to vscode, give a  if you're interested: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/154465

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Author Credit: https://github.com/danielsamuels

For those of you who are looking for a short term fix for this, I've created an [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script which provides middle-click Go To Definition behaviour:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
#IfWinActive ahk_exe Code.exe
~MButton::
MouseGetPos, xpos, ypos

if (ypos >= 87) {
    SendInput,{Click}{F12}
}

return
```

Copy the above contents into a file named vscode-f12-go-to-definition.ahk and run it. You'll see a green H icon in your systray which shows it's running.

Comment: Thanks, it's doing the job!

Comment: I'm glad to help!

Comment: Thanks!  Not sure why this isn't baked in.  Guess nobody told the kids at VSCode about the 'ole middle-click "open in new window" convention.